# Create and populate temporary Playlist Spotify Apps

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm developing using Spotify Apps and I have a list of Spoftify URIs tracks that I want to play. Is there any way to create a dynamic temporary Playlist to reproduce them?

I've tried the following and Spotify crashes:

```
var myTemporaryPlaylist = new models.Playlist(); //I create a new Playlist object
myTemporaryPlaylist._collections(); //Then the "track" property appears
myTemporaryPlaylist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:blablabla')) //being blablabla a real URI...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I don't know how to populate the Playlist with my URI Tracks...

I'm using 1.0 API if that helps.

Many thanks...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a temporary playlist by using

```
var playlist = models.Playlist.createTemporary("My temporary playlist");
```

You shouldn't use the default constructor to create playlists. If you want to create a regular playlist, simply use the create method instead.

In order to add tracks to a playlist, you need to first load the playlist's tracks. This is done for performance reasons. For example,

```
models.Playlist.createTemporary("A temporary playlist").done(function(playlist) { 
    playlist.load("tracks").done(function(loadedPlaylist) {
         loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:2Vy4z1ZUN7RvN7syWI2yef"));
         loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:2pj2VXKSBRTmV8nuiaCKd2"));
    });
});
```

Read more about [playlists here](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models-playlist.html).

Comment: I get always this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function Playlist(a) ... has no method 'createTemporary'`. And no idea, why.

Comment: Are you possibly using the legacy API? (version 0.x) https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/0.1/c49e02a392.html